# How to use Command Prompt after ng serve was compiled

Tags: node.js, angular, command-prompt, bootstrap-4

In Angular 5, after creating project folder, installing Angular CLI, Node.js (all latest versions) and ng serve was compiled successfully through command prompt. Then I tried to use command prompt to install bootstrap. I could not control / use command prompt. What might be the cause and effect?

[Command prompt stuck after compilation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itZ8L.jpg)

Comment: open another command prompt

Comment: yep i tried it. even though not working

Comment: i think you are not in the same path. it must work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are simple ways:

1. If you use **Command Prompt(Terminal)**, open another Command Prompt inside your project path.
2. If you use IDE like Visual Studio Code, open Terminal and then you can use **Plus(+) sign** for openning anothor Terminal like below image:

[image: Visual Studio Code Terminal]

3. If you use IDE like **WebStrom (Jetbrains IDE)**, first open IDE Terminal then make right click and select **New Session** and new terminal openning like below image:

[image: WebStorm Teminal]

Answer (score 4):

There are couple of ways you can do that.

- The [official way of deployment of angular app](https://angular.io/guide/deployment).
- Create a start.bat (if you are using windows) and write the `ng serve --open` command there. Now you can run this file which will internally run your angular app, using [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) or [pm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) npm modules.

If you do that these will demonise your process to run in background and your same command prompt becomes usable again.

Answer (score -1):

Once the process is finished( compiled successfully), you would notice that the cmd -prompt newline doesn't show any directory and its blank.
This means that, you just have to open an another (new terminal), get to the right directory using "cd command "and implement your desired commands or operations again.

Answer (score -3):

use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> it will ask **weather** to terminate say **Y**, cursor will go back